# C++ lambdas passing

Tags: c++11, lambda

This is just theoretical question. When i execute this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdio>

struct A {

    int value = 100;

    A() {
        printf("A\n");
    }

    A(const A& a) {
        printf("copy A\n");
    }

    ~A() {
        printf("~A\n");
    }
};

void function(std::function<int()> lambda) {
    printf("%d\n", lambda());
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto lambda = [a]() -> int {
        return a.value;
    };

    function(lambda);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is this:

```
A
copy A
copy A
copy A
100
~A
~A
~A
~A
```

And my question is why struct A is copied 3 times, not 2? 
One copy takes lambda capture, second takes passing argument to function and third takes what?

Comment: I can see two copies: one is `[a]`, next is when you it to function `std::function<int()> lambda`

Comment: `std::function` can hold any kind of callable entity, that is, represents a type-erased function enity. Thats done through a lot of policy classes and a bit of template metaprogramming. I think the lambda functor could be copied inside `std::function` implementation during its initialization. As you captured by value, when the functor is copied the captured variables are copied too.

Comment: I only get two copies with msvc :v

Comment: `function` should be a template instead of taking an `std::function`.

Comment: @rightfold its true, using `std::function` as argumment instead of just a template prevents inlining, but thats not the point of the question.

Comment: Are you using GCC? GCC's `std::function` ctor implementation says "Builds a %function that targets a copy of the incoming function object." http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01173_source.html (Line 2077)

Comment: So there are three copies: Capture, lambda functor pass at `std::function` initialization, and `lambda` by value pass to `function`.

Comment: @Manu343726 I am using GCC CLang on Mac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see the same number of copy operations, if you change your code as follows:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    auto&& lambda = [a]() -> int {
        return a.value;
    };
    std::function<int()>{lambda};
}
```

The first copy/move construction occurs when creating the lambda. The second and third copy/move constructions happen during construction of the *std::function*. According to N3690, the used constructor of *std::function* looks as follows:

```
template <class F> function(F);
```

That means, the passed argument will be copied/moved once when passing the argument to the constructor. Within the constructor, it will be copied/moved another time for type erasure.

If the constructor would use references instead (e.g. with *perfect forwarding*), you would only see two copy/move constructions. However, I don't know why it wasn't used in this case.

```
template <typename Arg> function(Arg&&);
```

Comment: +1 Thats exactly what I was thinking. I have checked GCC's implementation and there is no rvalue templated ctor. That explains the three copies. However, someone have tried that using MSVC and only obtained two copies. So possibly MSVC has an rvalue templated ctor.

Comment: Thank you. Nice explanation! I would never find it on my own :D
And i said it is only theoretical question. Of course while using references it will be not copied...